# No linking to PDF files since Jabref 3.2 upgrade

Tags: jabref

I have upgraded to Jabref 3.2 from a 2.* version.

Since the upgrade, I cannot open the PDF file associated to the BibTeX key of an entry. When right clicking on an entry, "Open file" is disabled in the menu.

My BibTeX keys are of the form "author2016", and the files "author2016.pdf" in a folder that is set as the main files directory in the "External programs" tab of the preferences.

Any idea of what has gone wrong?

Comment: Is this a JabRef issue? You click into a window of a gui of JabRef? Or do you compile a *.tex document and something what worked, ceased to do so? Please provide much more details...

Comment: Are you perhaps using the pdf field to link pdfs, e.g., in your entry something like `pdf = {author2016.pdf}`. The pdf field has been deprecated for several years and from version 3.0 onwards JabRef dropped support for it. However, there is migration functionality and it could probably work if you just replaced `pdf` with `file`. For further help, I need to see your BibTeX entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a change of behaviour between the old and new versions of JabRef. Now, the links to PDF files must appear explicitely in the database (in a `file` field).

The links can be created automatically from the BibTeX keys of a database by going to the "Quality" menu and then "Synchronize file links".

See also https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/1129